# how to clear the gmdatepicker value in the textbox

Tags: c#, datepicker

how to clear the gmdatepicker value in the textbox

i have a Datepicker where i pass the value while inserting into the table as

frmdate.Date

it will store my date which im selecting in the datepicker

but how to clear this selected value in the textbox once the value is inserted???????

Comment: @ranjana have you tried TxtboxID.value = "";

Comment: but it is not the textbox ya, it is a datetime picker.

i have got it atlast. frmdate.Reset() which clears out the selected value

Answer (score 3):

`DatePickerID.Reset()` is the solution to clear the datepicker content.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible because the datetimepicker is based on DateTime Value and DateTime isn't Nullable. So, the possibility is to cheked or unechecked the datetimePicker (with the property Checked) or use another control, like the DateTimePicker form ComponentOne.

Julien